# angular defnitly typed does not compile into js

Tags: angularjs, typescript

i installed the type script on my VS2013

i got the angular 1.5 definitly typed from Nuget package manager

angular.d.ts and it components does not generate angular.js but when i create other type script file such as file1.ts the file1.js generated too and i can use this file into the project .

how can i fix it ?

[compiled into JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptwmY.jpg)

[Does not Compiled Into JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3pT9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript files which have file name with .d.ts are not generated to js and it is not needed because .d.ts files only holds interfaces and shapes of code. You need to download angular.js library separately. You can use same Nuget package manager for this purpose.

Comment: can u please give me the nuget package adress ?

Comment: plase can you give me  a sample that how to use d.ts files